# when use auth('api')->user() in class `AppServiceProvider` return null

Tags: laravel-5

when use auth('api')->user() in class `AppServiceProvider` return null

this code `config/auth`

`'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],`

`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

`

this is code function boot in class `AppServiceProvider`

`view()->composer('dashboard::layouts.*', function ($view) {
            dd(auth('api')->user());
            $view->with('user', auth('api')->user());
        });`

Comment: why are you using `auth('api')` ?  Is that a custom function? 
If you using laravel default authentication system then you should `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 0):

you use session or token in your app? if you use token you should include token in your header request so if token did not send you get null user because the user is not authenticated, but if you use session so just use `Auth::user()` to get authenticated user

Comment: i.m use token -
and
 - i can not send token in the header Do you exist certain way send token in the header and thank you very

Answer (score 0):

send token in header most time is possible with Bearer prefix like:Bearer token_value, and if you use nginx add token value to Authorization parameter in header, dont forget add client middleware to your route.
for get authenticated user info you can do with this:

```
 $token = $request->bearerToken();
 $tokenId = (new Parser())->parse($token)->getHeader('jti');
    $client = Token::find($tokenId);
    return $client['user_id'];
```